# Translate this Excel formula into VBA code (function)

Tags: vba, excel, function

This is the formula in Excel that I'm trying to convert to VBA code:

```
=IFERROR(IF(effDate>curDate,0,IF((curDate-effDate+1)>nDays,nDays*(nSpend/365),((nSpend/365)*(curDate-effDate+1))-IF((curDate-effDate+1)-nDays>0,nSpend/365,0))),0)
```

For checking working purposes here are the values for each variable:

```
effDate: 1/1/17 (dimmed as value)
curDate: 3/31/17 (dimmed as value)
nDays: 60
nSpend: 1600
```

Correct answer: `263`

I tried to make it work for two days now and I retyped in about a hundred different way and none of them work. The code may work for one cell but it doesn't calculate correctly for the others. Or it doesn't work at all. Here is one of the examples of what I made earlier (name of the function is APFcst):

```
If effDate > curDate then
APFcst = 0 
Exit Function 
End if

If (curDate - effDate + 1) > nDays then
APFcst = nDays * (nSpend / 365) 
Else
val1 = (nSpend / 365) * (curDate - effDatea + 1)
end if 

if (curDate - effDate + 1) - nDays > 0 then
val2 = nSpend / 365
else
val2 = 0
end if

APFcst = val1 - val2
Exit Function 
End if
```

NOTE: everything is dimmed properly, the issue that I'm having is just translating the actual formula so it'll give me the correct answer. 
Please help! I've been staring at this for so long that I might not see an obvious solution.

Comment: Why not try a somewhat direct translation? `If()` (the worksheet function) corresponds to the VBA function `IIF()` and `IFERROR` can be prefixed by `Application.WorksheetFunction.` and directly used in Excel VBA.

Comment: APFcst = iff(effDate > curDate, 0, IIf((curDate - effDate + 1) > nDays, nDays * (nSpend / 365), ((nSpend / 365) * (curDate - effDate + 1)) - IIf((curDate - effDate + 1) - nDays > 0, nSpend / 365, 0)))   This is what I tried but its giving me an error (sub/function not defined). My coding skills are very beginner so Im not sure how to fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After noticing that the last `IF` check in your formula is redundant, here's a simplification of your equation:

```
Function xAPFcst(effDate, curDate, nSpend, nDays) As double
  xAPFcst = IIf(effDate > curDate, 0, (nSpend / 365) * Application.Min(nDays, curDate - effDate + 1))
End function
```

Comment: What is "min"? It's asking me to define it but i'm not sure what it is. Sorry my coding skills are very beginner! Just learning.

Comment: @KateLO `Application.Min`, using the function available in Excel :)

Comment: @ A.S.H I have other formulas within the same function and they are currently set as long. Will changing it to double change functionality of everything else or I could also use as long for this?

Comment: @KateLO sure you can use long, but you would be rounding the result if the division yields a decimal. It all depends on your project.

Comment: @ A.S.H sounds good! I just tried to implement it that way but the result turns out to be 0.  (    ElseIf freq = 0 Then
    xAPFcst = IIf(effDate > curDate, 0, (nSpend / 365) * Application.Min(nDays, curDate - effDate + 1))
End If). I cant seem to find an error.

Comment: @KateLO maybe because `effDate > curDate` is true? try putting some `Debug.Print effDate, curDate` before it ans see the results in the immediate window. Or try to follow the code step-by-step using `F8`.

Comment: I can assure you that this equation translates exactly your initial formula and simplifies it.

Comment: @ A.S.H It works! Thank you so much!!! I have one last function that I'm trying to do the same thing with that's much longer, could you tell me how you simplified the initial one? I'm new to this site so I cant chat but I could at least use a couple of useful hints and such :)  Thanks!

Comment: KateLO With pleasure. The first thing i noticed is that your last `IF` in the initial formula is always `False` where it is placed, so I dropped it and took the `false` case. The rest is translating from Excel's `IF` to VBA's `IIf`, and was already hinted by @JohnColeman` in the comments section.

Comment: oh that makes sense. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe possible to shorten it a touch using IIF's and perhaps, looking at using `(nSpend / 365)` a bit more effectively, i'll take a look again later.  I've not properly tested as yet.

```
Function formula_test(dtCurrentDate As Date, dtEffectiveDate As Date, nDays As Long, nSpend As Double) As Double

On Error GoTo eHandle

If dtEffectiveDate > dtCurrentDate Then
    formula_test = 0
Else
    If ((dtCurrentDate - dtEffectiveDate) + 1) > nDays Then
        formula_test = nDays * (nSpend / 365)
    Else
        formula_test = ((nSpend / 365) * (dtCurrentDate - dtEffectiveDate + 1))
        If (dtCurrentDate - dtCurrentDate + 1) - nDays > 0 Then
            formula_test = formula_test - nSpend / 365
        End If
    End If
End If

Exit Function

eHandle:
        formula_test = 0

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My coding skills are very beginner (just heads up). I just tried to implement the code but it gives me a 0 for some reason.

Comment: `formula_test(dateserial(2017,3,31),dateserial(2017,1,1),60,1600)` =  263.013698630137